# Executing recurring payments with the REST Api

Tags: python, paypal

I need to use recurring payments with PayPal, so for every 30 days I will subtract a payment from the customer.

There is so much information about PayPal that I'm totally lost.

So, there a is way of doing recurring payments with the Rest Api? https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python

Best Regards,
Andre

Comment: AFAIK paypal don't provide REST recurring payments, you may use the classic APIs or vault. Check this thread on github https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs/issues/3

Answer (score 2):

I have looked through all of the documentation for PayPal Payments Standard, and found no Rest API Recurring Billing references, unless you use PayPal Vault.

Here is the reference documentation for **PayPal Vault:**

[PayPal Vault Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#vault)

There are other ways to setup **Recurring Payments** with PayPal Payments Standard accounts.
 
You can use **Express Checkout** to create **Recurring Payments APIs.**
 
Here is a link to the documentation for **Express Checkout** and recurring payments:
[PayPal Express Checkout Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)

Another option for you is to create a simple subscription button. You can create the button directly in your PayPal Account by going to the **Merchant Services Tab**, and choosing **Create Payment Buttons for your website** then choose **Subscription**.
The other option for you is to manually create the subscription button.
Here is the documentation on Creating a Subscription Button:
[PayPal Subscription Button Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/)

These are the basic options for PayPal Payments Standard.